# Getting error: File extension specified '.webtest' is not a valid test extension

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Trying to run `MSTEST.exe` which I installed via `Agents For Visual Studio 2017` download (https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) on TFSAgent

Trying to run

`MSTest.exe /TestContainer:C:\agent\_work\3\a\stack\tests\WebTest1.webtest /resultsfile:C:\agent\_work\3\a\stack\tests\webtest.trx /testsettings:C:\agent\_work\3\a\stack\tests\Local.testsettings`

Results in error below

```
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.0.26208.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading C:\agent\_work\3\a\stack\tests\Local.testsettings...
Loading C:\agent\_work\3\a\stack\tests\webtest1.webtest...
C:\agent\_work\3\a\stack\tests\webtest1.webtest
File extension specified '.webtest' is not a valid test extension.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Load & Performance Testing is supported in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, you need to install Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 with Web Performance and Load testing tools.

If you still get the error after installing VS2017 Enterprise, try opening the IDE as the user who will be running the tests and then invoking MSTest.

More information about VS 2017 supported features, you can refer to: [Compare Visual Studio 2017 IDEs](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/)

Comment: So it's impossible to use this tool just to running tests without full blown VS 2017 along with GUI installed on agent computer? I just need this to run webtests.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian No, I think you need install VS enterprise 2017.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I prematurely upvoted. I have VS2017 Ent, upgraded to most recent, installed the Web Perf and Load Testing Tools, installed the Test Manager but still get the error: `'.webtest' is not a valid test extension` - is there anything else you can suggest to check? Running via cmd prompt or via TFS Build both produce the same error.

Comment: @JeremyThompson in case anyone else runs into this - simply opening VS2017 as the user that will be running the webtest solved this.  Something under the hood gets linked to the enterprise capabilities once you open up the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Installed evaluation version of VS Enterprise 2017 and MSTEST.exe working fine. Not sure if it's time limited bomb or not though.

[Link with details](https://artisticcheese.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/integrating-docker-release-management-in-tfs-with-webtests/)