# Running .webtest tests results in ".webtest is not a valid extension"

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2017, mstest

I'm using VS2017 - is there any way to get webtests working without installing VS2017 Enterprise?  All I need is `mstest.exe` - not the GUI or IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for unit test you can install [Agents For Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/zh-hans/downloads/).

But for   Web Load & Performance Testing, it is only supported in Visual Studio Enterprise 2017, So you need to install Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 with Web Performance and Load testing tools.

More information about VS 2017 supported features, you can refer to: [Compare Visual Studio 2017 IDEs](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/)

Reference below threads:

- [Getting error: File extension specified '.webtest' is not a valid test extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45339584/getting-error-file-extension-specified-webtest-is-not-a-valid-test-extension)
- [Can I use mstest.exe without installing Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402899/can-i-use-mstest-exe-without-installing-visual-studio)